# Continuity in Brouwer fixed point theorem is a necessary condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to construct an example to show that the continuity of a function is a necessary condition for the Brouwer fixed point theorem. I think that it maybe easy to construct a discontinuous function on some compact interval of R but I am unable to construct one. Any help/hint is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

$f:[0,1]\longrightarrow[0,1]$ defined by $f(x)=1-x$ has one fixed point.  If you redefine the function at that point, it will have no fixed point.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f : [0,1]\to [0,1]$$
$$x \mapsto \frac 12( 2-\lfloor x \rfloor )$$

then
$$(\forall x\in[0,1))\;\; f(x)=1\ne x$$
and
$$f(1)=\frac 12 \ne 1$$

Comment: This does not map back to $[0,1]$ though.

Comment: @SvenPistre Thanks.  I just edited. is it good now.